# How to offest and paste current clipboard data with an IF statement

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a script that copies and pastes data from another workbook into a column on a different workbook. However, my code is static and only runs one time. What I am trying to do is copy and paste cells over to the new workbook, then the next time the code runs it will detect that there is already data within a range and shift over to the right one cell.

I was playing with the IF statement below and then I hit a wall. I suspect I have to put my copied data into a variable form of some sort then call upon it? right now it just puts the number "1" shifted over.... I do understand why that is....I just don't have enough knowledge to know how to insert what is already copied in my clipboard.

```
Sub makepropercellselection()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cellval As Range

Set cellval = Range("E9")

cellval.Select
If IsEmpty(cellval) = True Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    cellval.Offset(0, 1) = 1
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Weird, there's another question from a few minutes ago where the guy wanted to do the same thing but he was copying but not pasting... You're pasting but not copying...  You two should hook up.

Comment: Very interesting comment. ha ha ha.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always starting at E9 and only offsetting 1 cell rather than continuing to search for the first blank cell in row 9. One way is like so. If you continually run this it will put a 1 in F9, G9, H9 etc.

```
Sub makepropercellselection()

Dim c As Long
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject

Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
On Error GoTo err1
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
mystring = DataObj.GetText(1)
c = Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Cells(9, WorksheetFunction.Max(5, c)).PasteSpecial
Exit Sub

err1:
   If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox "Data on clipboard is not text or is empty"

End Sub
```

Comment: That does seem to be a better way. However, the main problem is that I do not need a 1 in the column, I need what is in my clipboard.

Comment: Where are you doing the copying and is it in Excel?

Comment: You could try `Cells(9, WorksheetFunction.Max(5, c)).PasteSpecial`.

Comment: Code above amended (courtesy of elsewhere at SO), though if you're copying in Excel you don't need all this.

Comment: That code seems to work. I am copying in Excel, what would be better?

Comment: See @ashleedawg's answer.

Comment: after further looking at the code, it rewrites over the first cycle where the code is called to paste to. How do I prevent this from happening? I am generating multiple reports and trending historical data. This code does shift until it finds an empty slot, but rewrites over from where it is calling the shift from, thus erasing my original historical data.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about what you're doing and how your data are laid out.

Comment: Okay, thank so much for your help! I definitely learned a more efficient way of offsetting that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store copied information in a cell.  It's stored in the Windows clipboard.

**Basic example of copy & paste**:

```
Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
```

Copies `A1` and pastes the copy into `A2`.

**Basic example of copy & paste values:**

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Copies `A1` and pastes only the value into `A2`.

Comment: @Yes I agree this is a good way to copy and paste in excel...However in my original code I cannot paste in the ELSE part of my IF,THEN,ELSE statement. I need an object or variable I believe.